What is generated for a managed google play web app?
In the managed Google Play store, you have 3 different application types:

Managed Google Play store app
Managed Google Play private app
Managed Google Play web app

The managed Google Play web app generates an APK that is listed after a couple of minutes between your other native apps. But it opens in Chrome. Anybody knows what exactly is used behind the scenes. I searched the docs but could not find any info.
Is Google generating a Trusted Web Activity behind the scenes?
What about lifecycle management of the shell, do they do the housekeeping for me to target new android versions for the shell?
